# How to pass a large structure through JNI from C to JAVA

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

Is it possible to pass a large Structure through JNI from C to Java?

Can somebody please give me the possible solutions?

Comment: Normally, you need to create a Java structure which is a copy of  the C structure and pass that back. You cannot use C data types in Java (or visa-versa directly)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey may be you can help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215374/from-c-code-to-java-and-jni ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a pointer to the struct in your java class like so:

`protected long ptrToX;`

Next, to set it:

- Get the field ID using `(*env)->GetFieldID(...)`
- Get the pointer using `(*env)->GetLongField(...)`
- Set the pointer using `(*env)->SetLongField(...)`

To get it, just follow the first two steps mentioned above.

Always remember to include a finaliser that will take care of deallocating the pointer when the object is garbage-collected.  Alternatively, if you do not want to incur the performance hit incurred by using finalisers, just provide a terminate() method that deallocates the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Better you switch to JNA, It's much convenient way to program from C to JAVA.